# How to read line by line in a custom Django upload handler?

Tags: python, django

I am handling *large* [SDF files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_table_file) (~multiple GB) and want to calculate the number of molecules in each of them and store that in the database. Right now I do it as a separate loop after the file has been uploaded but that means iterating through the file one extra time which takes long time and is done after the file has been uploaded so gives no progress info to the user.

My plan is to instead count the number of lines being equal to: `$$$$` in a custom upload handler and then place that number on the model somehow and save the model. I am still quite new to Python though and I got completely stumped when I realised that I get a chunk of data and could not find a good way to read line by line from the upload. Is there some Handler in Django already which reads line by line which I could use or do I have to make my own? If I do have to make my own, what sort of datastructure should I use as local cache to keep it speedy in my handler considering the large size of the total data?

This is what I have so far:  :)

```
class CountSDFEntries(FileUploadHandler):
    def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
        return raw_data

    def file_complete(self, file_size):
        return None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this code:

```
class CountSDFEntries(FileUploadHandler):

    def __init__(self, request, datasetModel):
        FileUploadHandler.__init__(self, request)
        self.datasetModel = datasetModel

    cache = ""
    numofmols = 0
    datasetModel = None;

    def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
        self.cache += raw_data
        lines = self.cache.splitlines()
        self.cache = lines[-1]
        del lines[-1]
        for line in lines :
            if line.rstrip() == "$$$$":
                self.numofmols += 1
        return raw_data

    def file_complete(self, file_size):
        #The last line is still in the cache, so + 1
        self.datasetModel.numberOfMols = self.numofmols + 1 
        return None
```

However, there is still a long waiting time after the file has been uploaded which I now wonder if it might be from when Django moves the file from `/tmp/` into where the file should be in the end. So this didn't really fix my problem of long waiting times after the file has been uploaded. :(